# Regex for Zapier to extract dollar amount

Tags: zapier

I'm using Zapier to pull dollar amounts out of emailed invoices to process them.

My first step in Zapier is a new email matching a search query, and I am able to get it to find the right email fine. To pull the $ amount out, I run a second step, Formatter by Zapier, and use transform -> extract pattern. For the regex pattern, I thought `^\$(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|(([1-9]\d*)?\d))(\.\d\d)?$` would work - but it's turning up false/no data.

Any one have any ideas that I should try? I'm admittedly not great at regex so I may have made a mistake above, so really appreciate any advice!

I would want to be able to pull any dollar amount format; but, the email will only have 1 per email, so it would just need to pull the first/only instance of the dollar amount in the email; it is in the body text of the email, and in format of either $X.XX, $XX.XX, $XXX.XX, or $X,XXX.XX (depends each instance).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using this

```
[\$ ]+?(\d+([,\.\d]+)?)
```

I ran some basic tests using the examples you gave and this should work. Alternatively, you may be able to get this out by using two Formatter - Split steps. One with a "$" delimiter, another with a " " blank space.

The first Index should be the result you're looking for there.

Comment: Thank you! This works - really appreciate it. It brings the result out as $XX.XX. - including the last period, as the invoice amount is in the email at the end of a sentence - so I will play around with that (unless you have an idea to remove any punctuation that may follow the dollar amount?).